# Reading from properties file in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a web application in which I'm using spring MVC. I have defined few constants in `sample.properties` file. spring-servlet is the servlet that gets initialized for all urls in my app. spring-servlet:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:sample.properties"/>
</beans>
```

In one of my java classes I access the value of one of the properties like this:

```
package com.sample;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Validator {

    @Value("${credit}")
    String credits;

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Validator.class);

    public void checkRating() {
        LOG.debug(credits);
    }
}
```

sample.properties:

```
credit=[{"duration":15,"credit":10},{"duration":30,"credit":20}]
```

When Validator is called from a controller, it just logs it as `${credit}` in my log file. I dont get its value. Similarly, if I put an integer / floating point number in the properties file, I get an error saying it cannot be cast into integer / float. Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: Please confirm it again that properties file is placed under classpath directly under bin or build folder.

Comment: This is a gradle based project. I have placed it under src/main/resources. It is there under build directory also (resources/main/sample.properties).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem or what version of Spring you're running. But try updating the XSD to the proper versions. It now uses `3.0` which might not be the correct version to use.

Comment: I changed it to 3.2 now since I'm using 3.2.4.RELEASE. But still no luck :(

Comment: I fixed it by placing the context:property-placeholder in applicationContext.xml instead of spring-servlet.

Comment: How do I read data of non-string type from properties file? I get an exception: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Double'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because propertyplaceholder configurer is a [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) and it processess only the beans defined in the context in which the propertyplaceholder is configured. In a web application typically there is a heirarchy of context as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619539/understanding-contexts-in-spring-mvc). Hence you need to declare this at appropriate place.