# How exactly are the root context and the dispatcher servlet context into a Spring MVC web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am studying **Spring MVC** and I have some doubt related

So, I have this configuration class that configure my **DispatcherServlet** that handle the user requests:

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {

        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = ...
        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

       dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);

       // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
       ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("main", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
       dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
       dispatcher.addMapping("main/");
   }
}
```

It is pretty clear for me how the **DispatcherServlet** works. My doubts are related to the **context** concept.

1) What exactly represent a **context**? I think that is something like a set of beans that have a specific pourpose and that works togheter into an environment. But I am absolutly not true about this assertion.

2) What is the difference between the **root context** and the **dispatcher servlet context**?

3) From what I have understand the beans defined in **dispatcherContext** have access to beans defined in **rootContext** (but the opposite is not true). Why?

Tnx

Comment: Your WAR file is the context.

Comment: Beans/configuraiton loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` is the root context, everything loaded by a `DispatcherServlet` (or `MessageDispatcherServlet` for Spring-WS) is a child context. You can have multiple servlets which all have access to the root context (should contain shared resources like services, etc.). Now if you have 10 dispatcher servlets, which servlet should be accessed by the root context? Hence only the parent is accessible from the child and not the other way around. This would also lead to issues with AOP, suddenly AOP defined by the child would influence the parent.

Comment: @M.Deinum Tnx so much, perfect explaination. If you put it as a response I will accept it :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619539/understanding-contexts-in-spring-mvc

Comment: [link1](http://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/Spring-ContextLoaderListener-And-DispatcherServlet-Concepts) , [link2](http://www.deroneriksson.com/tutorials/java/spring/introduction-to-the-spring-framework/configuring-root-web-application-context-in-spring-web-application) have good explanations.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### Root Context

The root-context in a Spring application is the `ApplicationContext` that is loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`. This context should have globally available resources like services, repositories, infrastructure beans (`DataSource`, `EntityManagerFactory`s etc.) etc.

The `ContextLoaderListener` registers this context in the `ServletContext` under the name `org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT`.

*If you load an `ApplicationContext` yourself and register it with the name above in the `ServletContext` that will then qualify as the root-context.*

### Child Context

The child-context in a Spring application is the `ApplicationContext` that is loaded by a `DispatcherServlet` (or for instance a `MessageDispatcherServlet` in a Spring-WS application). This context should only contain beans relevant to that context, for Spring MVC that would be `ViewResolver`s, `HandlerMapping`s etc.

The servlet registers this context in the `ServletContext` under the name `org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.<servlet-name>`.

### Root <-Child Relation

Only child contexts have access to the parent context, because you could have multiple child contexts. For instance in an Spring MVC combined with Spring WS application. The parent-context is detect by the children by finding it in the `ServletContext` with the well known name.

If the root context would have access to the child which one would it use to wire beans? Next to that if that would be the case you would also get surprising results when AOP is involved. AOP defined in the child context would suddenly influence beans configured in the root context.

Comment: Great!, Very concise explanation.

Comment: Could you provide any example how to achieve 1 root contexts and 2 child contexts ?

Comment: That is already mentioned in the answer, like Spring MVC and Spring WS combined. However there is also nothing preventing you from creating multiple DispatcherServlet instances.